# Will a virtual machine continue running when the host goes to sleep?

Tags: minecraft

If the host machine (physical PC) goes into hibernation or sleep mode,
will the VM stay running? If I was hosting a game server (e.g. TF2, Gmod, Minecraft), will the server (the VM for that matter) keep running?

Comment: Can you give details about the host machine? Linux or Windows? Maybe your title should be more related to the question, too. It is currently just as vague as saying _Minecraft Help_.

Comment: If you want to disable hibernation and/or sleep on Win7: [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 3):

If the host machine goes to sleep, then everything it is doing, such as running a virtual machine, will stop. When the host machine wakes up, then it will resume its tasks, at which time, any virtual machines it hosts will start running again as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, when a computer sleeps, what ever it is doing is stored in the hard drive and not used and processing basically stops, this means that what ever is happening will be halted. (Maybe you can use a [Raspberry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), I personally never tried it but I think it can be a 24 hour server if you configure it)